# JS $.get or $.getScript pass data to file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass data to the js file. however cant get is to work.

```
js='article.js';

function loadjs(js){
$.get(js,{ name: "test" });
}
```

article.js

```
alert(name);
```

if i do alert('test'); i get a response from the file so i know it works.
also cant use globals.

is there a simple way to send the data to the file and show it?

EDIT to clarify
(yes i can use angelar but i dont)

Onload it triggers 'pagina' with all short of variables. (its dynamic).
all the 'php/html' files are loaded.
and you get what you can see in the link. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H0Am.jpg)

hoverever when i click on a row i want function pagina(); to load the content of the row so far so good. however to show the data that i want. I want to send a ID to the JS file and use a $.post (php) in the JS file to get data json. if i set a ID in $.post id=1 directly its works.

so to not let it be more confusing. i want to send a id to a js file JS $.get or $.getScript.

```
function pagina(menu,frame,vars,crum,js,togglezoeken,voorwaarden){
'use strict';
if(!menu){$('#frame').show();}
if(menu){
$('#loader-zoeken').hide(); 
$('#loader-bijwerken').hide();  
$('#loader-pagina').show(); 
$('#menu').hide();
$('#frame').empty();
$('#menu').load(menu+vars,{noncache: new Date().getTime()}, function() {$('#menu').foundation();});}    
if(crum==1){$('#breadcrumbs').load('/opbouw/frames/breadcrumbs.php?'+vars,{noncache: new Date().getTime()}, function() {});}
$('#frame').load(frame+vars+'&crum='+crum,{noncache: new Date().getTime()}, function() {
if(togglezoeken){$('#uitgebreidzoeken').toggle();}
if(crum==1){$('#breadcrumbs').show();}else{$('#breadcrumbs').hide();}

if(js){
$.get( js,{ name: "test" });
}
else{
$('#loader-pagina').hide();
$('#menu').show();
$('#frame').show();
}
//if(voorwaarden==1){popup('/opbouw/frames/voorwaarden.php','','/opbouw/js/voorwaarden.js');}
$('#frame').foundation();
});
}
```

Comment: why the file isn't imported as first load ?

Comment: there is a reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way. `$.get` is used for AJAX/HTTP(s) requests and your file in that way won't accept the data sent to it.

To achive this you have to use a server-side endpoint on your `article.js`.

Lets say:

```
function loadjs( js ) {
    $.get(js, { name: "test" });
}
```

And you make a call of `loadjs` function:

```
loadjs('article.js');
```

On your server you have to have an server-side endpoint directing to a request: `/article.js`:

You can achieve this by using PHP or `express` for node.js:

```
router.get('article.js', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json( req.query.data );
});
```

Or in PHP (note in Apache you have to use `mod_rewrite` and enable it with `.htaccess` or in your virtual host configuration):

```
$req = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($req == 'article.js') {
    echo json_encode(array('data' => $_GET['data']));
    exit(0); // end the script here
}
```

In either way used from above you have effectivelly sent a data to your script / endpoint and you can handle it further.

Although your `loadjs` function just sends a request and doesn't handle a response, you can do the following with a callback function in `$.get`:

```
$.get(js, { name: "test" }, function(data) {
    alert(data); // you will alert the data from the JSON response
});
```

Sadly, you haven't described what you actually need and this is as far as I can help you with so far.